# How to update nltk package so that it does not break email into 3 different tokens?

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

When I type following code:
`tokens = word_tokenize("a@b.com")`

It gets broken into these 3 tokens: 'a' , '@' , 'b.com'

What I want to do, is to keep it as a single token 'a@b.com'.

Comment: As your own choice of tags suggests, a possible solution is to use the `RegexpTokenizer`, defining yourself what should be considered a token. This has nothing to do with updating the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*DISCLAIMER: There are a lot of email regexps out there. I am not trying to match all email formats in this question, just showing an example*.

A regex approach with `RegexpTokenizer` ([mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777806/how-to-update-nltk-package-so-that-it-does-not-break-email-into-3-different-toke#comment66852179_39777806) by [lenz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1698431/lenz)) can work:

```
from nltk.tokenize.regexp import RegexpTokenizer
line="My email: a@bc.com is not accessible."
pattern = r'\S+@[^\s.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+|\w+|[^\w\s]'
tokeniser=RegexpTokenizer(pattern)
tokeniser.tokenize(line)
# => ['My', 'email', ':', 'a@bc.com', 'is', 'not', 'accessible', '.']
```

The regex matches:

- `\S+@[^\s.]+\.[a-zA-Z]+` - text looking like email:

  - `\S+`  - 1 or more non-whitespace chars
  - `@` - a `@` symbol
  - `[^\s.]+` - 1 or more chars other than whitespaces and `.`
  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - 1 or more word chars (letters, digits, or underscores)
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - a single (add `+` after it to match a sequence of 1 or more) occurrence of a char other than a word and whitespace char.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bDfeYV/1).